# Use Gauss’s theorem to calculate the flux of F through S (Solution wanted ASAP)

Tags: calculus

So, for this particular question, I'm not sure about the flux you will obtain in the end. I've applied Gauss's theorem correctly (at least, in my opinion), but I don't know if my answer is the right one. (Also I got a different answer when I spotted a mistake while trying to correct what I already had.) So a detailed solution would be very much appreciated.

The question is listed below:

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot better if you posted *your* solution for us to see what you did right or wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In words: Note that the divergence of $\mathbf F$ is $1+1-2=0$, so the flux of $\mathbf F$ outward across $S$ is equal to the flux of $\mathbf F$ upward across the disk of radius $1$ in the plane $z=1$. But that flux is $0$, since the $\mathbf k$-component of $\mathbf F$ is $0$ on $z=1$. Thus, the answer is $0$.

**EDIT**: In symbols, we have this. $S$ is the surface of the exponential paraboloid, oriented with normal pointing upward. Let $D^-$ be the disk $x^2+y^2\le 1$, $z=1$, oriented with normal pointing downward; let $D^+$ be the same disk, oriented with normal pointing upward. Then $S\cup D^-$ is the boundary of a $3$-dimensional region $V$. By Gauß's Theorem, we have
$$\iiint_V \text{div}\,\mathbf F\,dV = \iint_{\partial V} \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = \iint_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS + \iint_{D^-} \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS.$$
Since $\text{div}\,\mathbf F = 0$, we have
$$\iint_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS + \iint_{D^-} \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = 0,$$
and so
$$\iint_S \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = -\iint_{D^-} \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = +\iint_{D^+} \mathbf F\cdot \mathbf n\,dS = 0,$$
since on $D^+$ we have $\mathbf n = \mathbf k$ and $\mathbf F\cdot\mathbf k = 2-2z=0$.

Comment: I am sorry, I just want to bring your attention to my question. As you mention in your profile, I will send an e-mail. Thank you.

Comment: Could you also give the solution in mathematical notation, since that's the part I'm struggling with?

Comment: @AdamWarlock: I have added a complete solution. In the future, I hope you will share more of your own work efforts.